Microsoft Intune no longer installable on Ubuntu 22.04
A few days ago Microsoft's Intune disappeared from the Ubuntu laptop. I tried to reinstall it, but there is a dependency problems. Did jammy move to a new version of this lib? Or did I mess something up?
sudo apt install ./intune-portal_1.2405.17-focal_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for *****: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'intune-portal' instead of './intune-portal_1.2405.17-focal_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 intune-portal : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
                 Depends: msalsdk-dbusclient (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


I don't know the intune app/package to which you refer, and an apt search doesn't find anything in Ubuntu repositories for my release, but your pasted detail show what appears to be a package intended for use on focal or 20.04 and not jammy or 22.04; thus dependencies would be expected to be different; deb packages are intentionally packaged for a specific release unless they're generic (eg. if a package contains only wallpapers it can be a generic package as pictures are data only & not tried to specific software*).

@guiverc. Thank you. I didn't see it. I kept copying and pasting the wrong block of commands from the web page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/microsoft-intune-app-linux

@guiverc Post it as an an answer and I'll accept. :-)

As stated in comment, I don't know the intune app/package to which you refer, and an apt search doesn't find anything in Ubuntu repositories for my release, but your pasted detail show what appears to be a package intended for use on focal or 20.04 and not jammy or 22.04; thus dependencies would be expected to be different; deb packages being intentionally packaged for a specific release unless they're generic (eg. if a package contains only wallpapers it can be a generic package as pictures are data only & not tied to specific software binaries)
